# How to format the table in rtf file while using it at ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rtf

table = document.table(5, 4) do |t|

t.border_width = 20

```
    t[0][0] << "Patient:"
    t[0][1] << "#{@patient.given_names} #{@patient.surname}"
    t[0][2] << "Date of Test:"
    t[0][3] << "#{@activity.seen_at.try(:strftime, "%d/%m/%Y")}"
```

This is the block of code that generates a table in .rtf file but the formatting of the cell is not good. I need help regarding the formatting of the .rtf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper formatting of the table can be done using following command

```
 table = document.table(5, 4)
 table.border_width = 20
  table.each do |row|
    row.each{ |cell| cell.width = 2000 }
  end
```